# springfox-swagger2 in spring3 MVC project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I am currently using **Spring3 MVC**.

Below is my project **pom.xml** information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>

        <org.springframework-version>3.2.15.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I wanted to use a **swagger** in my spring project, so I searched and applied it.

When I checked several articles, I saw that **"spring3"** does not use **"springfox-swagger2"**.

Currently, I am testing it by applying it as below, and the error as below occurs.

```
rg.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'swaggerParameterDescriptionReader' for bean class [springfox.documentation.swagger.readers.parameter.ApiParamParameterBuilder] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [springfox.documentation.swagger.readers.parameter.ParameterDescriptionReader]
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:312)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:253)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:130)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:410)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:410)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:287)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:632)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1651)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My question is,

- Can't I use **"springfox-swagger2"** in **"spring3 MVC"**?
- If **"springfox-swagger2"** is not available, which maven dependency should be used?
- How should I correct the error if it is available?

Comment: You could try [Swagger SpringMVC » 1.0.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mangofactory/swagger-springmvc/1.0.2) or the [oldest version of  springfox](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.0.1) but the latter it might now work

Comment: @LMC I saw your comment and lowered the version of swaggerfox to 2.0.1. 

However, "ConflictingBeanDefinitionException" still occurs as shown in the text. 

Do you happen to know why exceptions occur? I don't know how to solve it. :'(

Comment: springfox starts [sprinframework support at 4.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.0.1), look at dependencies there

Comment: @LMC I am using springframework 3.2.15.RELEASE, so springfox cannot be applied.. I'll try the swagger-springmvc. Thank you very much for letting me know!!

Answer (score 0):

springfox-swagger in later versions changed their name to `OpenApi`
https://swagger.io/specification/

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10</version>
   </dependency>
```

Please refer spring doc
https://springdoc.org/

Comment: Thank you for teaching me a new way! I checked the link you told me, but it was only possible with "Spring Boot". I'm using "Spring MVC" instead of boot, so I don't think I can use the library.